# How to read write some data in google spreadsheet in android?

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I have android application,
When user open the application i want to write some data in google spreadsheet(my google spreadsheet).

So that i can't force user to read / write using OAuth permission.

Can able to read write using **api key**.

Please suggest on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to use OAuth when performing Sheets API operation. To learn how to read cells, check the [Reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading) guide.

**Reading**

> To read data from a sheet, you will need the spreadsheet ID and the
>   range(s) A1 notation. For more information about spreadsheet IDs and
>   A1 notation, see [Key Concepts in the Google Sheets
>   API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts).

Check the [Samples page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/) for actual code snippets.